# Managing cookies in C# / Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm having trouble removing/adding cookies in Selenium.  I'm using Windows 7 and FireFox 25.0.1.  My code looks like this:

```
Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();

var _cookies = Instance.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;
Instance.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

foreach(Cookie cookie in _cookies)
{
    Instance.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);
}

var _newCookies = Instance.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies; //boom
```

On that last line I get the exception "Unexpected problem getting cookies."  I've tried several variants of the above code and the same problem occurs the second time I call `AllCookies`-- even after closing and reopening the browser and calling `GoToUrl(mysite)` and re-adding the cookies (The browser was on `mysite` when I saved the cookies).

I've checked the cookies collection before accessing it, and they all have name/value pairs.

Has anyone managed to use the cookie API successfully in Selenium for C# or can say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to get and read allCookies on each step when you adding new, it will help you to understood with each exactly cookie you have a problem

Answer (score 3):

You can only add cookies if your browser is displaying a page of the domain you want to drop the cookie on.

you don't appear to have navigated to a URL before dropping cookies.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  The same thing happens even when making calls to `Navigate().GoToUrl(my_domain)` before removing the cookies and adding them subsequently.

Comment: I have been able to use Chrome & C# to drop cookies.  However, these were cookies I just created rather than read, delete then add.  What happens when you just add the cookies rather than reading first?